# How to run this bot in this guide?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, trading

I'm trying to follow this guide to run a pump detector bot in python:

> [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH0Ib.png)
>
> Importing necessary libraries We need to add 2 functions to our code.
>
> play (musicfile, vol) is simple- it takes a musicfile from your system
> (.wav or .mp3) and sound volume (0–1) as user input and plays the file
> when alert is prompted. This function is being called inside a second
> function-
>
> run_alerts(URL,initial_data,sleeptime,vol)
>
> URL: The url of api that we are dealing with. we will configure this
> in further code.
>
> initial_data: The state of coin at the time when program is started.
>
> sleeptime: We need to check a percentage change in a percentage time.
> sleeptime is the frequency our program will hit the api with.
>
> Vol is the same as the above function.
>
> [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw5ZV.png)
> [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5oR2.png)
>
> Let’s run the code. Below, the parameters that i have used are 0.03%
> change in 15 seconds- which is only a dummy scenario. the 2 alerts are
> underlined below to show how it works.
>
> [image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLcbd.png)

I tried to run the code but it only shows the coins I have added:

```
Check this out
BTC, XRP, ETH, wave, gala, cro, ada, algo, atom, avax, axs, bnb, dodo, dot, doge, ftm, gmt, hbar, kava, ksm, link, ltc, mana, matic, near, sand, shib, sol, unfi, vra
```

But it doesn't show anything more as the guide has in image4. Is this because I haven't put the % change and time? And how can I put them in the code?